# MissingMethodException when trying to Eval in Groovy

Tags: groovy, scope

I am trying to dynamically evaluate a result of another function during a class method call. However, having and issue with the scope of the Eval.

```
class A {
    private String a
    public A() {
        a = 5
    }

    public whatIsA() {
        return a
    }


    public func() {
        return "\\${whatIsA()}"
    }

    public test() {
        return Eval.me("\"\${func()}\"")
    }
}
def a = new A()
a.test()



Exception thrown: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.func() is applicable for argument types: () values: {}

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.func() is applicable for argument types: () values: {}
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at A.test(Script7:17)
    at Script7.run(Script7:22)
```

How can I pass the scope of the A class instance into the Eval script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
class A {
    private String a
    public A() {
        a = 5
    }

    public whatIsA() {
        return a
    }

    public func() {
        return "${whatIsA()} + 5"
    }

    public test() {
        return Eval.me(func())
    }
}
def a = new A()
a.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in the current form...  The best I can come up with would be to either use `Eval.x` like so:

```
public test() {
    return Eval.x( this, '"${x.func()}"' )
}
```

Or wrap the expression in a closure (which you can then change the delegate on)

```
public test() {
  def clos = Eval.me( '{ -> func() }' )
  clos.delegate = this
  clos.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
  clos.call()
}
```

If you want this to run not as a Script, but as a compiled application, there are probably routes you can take with [GroovyScriptEngine](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.html) and/or [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html).  (See: [Evaluate Scripts with a Common Base Class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy))